# Send value from python GUI to an external file

Tags: python, user-interface

I need to have values from 2 sliders in a python GUI sent to an external file (just a text or csv file).Can anyone help?
Cheers
Alasdair

Comment: What is python GUI, by the way?

Comment: Short answer: When the value is available, open the file, write the value, and then close it. Does that not work for some reason?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick example using wx.Python:

```
import wx

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, id = -1):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id)

        self.slider1 = wx.Slider(self, -1, 50, 0, 100, size=(300,25))
        self.slider2 = wx.Slider(self, -1, 50, 0, 100, size=(300,25))

        self.button = wx.Button(self, -1, "Write Values")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onWrite)

        #  Uncomment the next two lines if you want to write the
        #  data out every time you move the slider
        #self.Bind(wx.EVT_SLIDER, self.onWrite)
        #self.onWrite()

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.AddStretchSpacer(1)
        self.sizer.Add(self.slider1, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
        self.sizer.AddSpacer(50)
        self.sizer.Add(self.slider2, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
        self.sizer.AddSpacer(75)
        self.sizer.Add(self.button, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
        self.sizer.AddStretchSpacer(1)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)

    def onWrite(self, event = None):
        v1 = self.slider1.GetValue()
        v2 = self.slider2.GetValue()
        f = open("file.csv", "w")
        line = "%d, %d\n" %(v1, v2)
        f.write(line)
        f.close()
        print "Just wrote", line


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = wx.PySimpleApp()
    f = wx.Frame(None,-1, "Slider Demo")
    p = MyPanel(f)
    f.Show()
    a.MainLoop()
```

Comment: @K. Brafford It writes to the file on each slide event?

Comment: Good point.  I wasn't sure based on the question, so I figured I'd show how to get notified of the slider changes.  I modded the example to write deliberately via button press.